# flot gets the data from json but shows blank graph

Tags: flot

This is the code, when i mannually paste the json data inplace of series the graph is obtained but through ajax call am able to get the json data but the chart is blank.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
            url:"sqljson.php",
            method:"GET",
            datatype:"json",
            success:graph
        })

        function graph(series){
                var data=series;

                alert(series);
                var options={
                lines:{show:true},
                points:{show:true,hoverable:true},
                grid:{hoverable:true,clickable:true}
                }

            $.plot($("#place"),[data], options);    
            }


    });
```

json data:obtained on the alert window

```
[["253","5"],["254","32"],["255","10"],["256","50"],["257","1"],["258","2"["259","100"],["260","38"],["261","2"],["262","20"],["263","2000"],["264","500"],    ["265","400"],["266","10"],["267","50"],["268","9"],["269","200"],["270","40"]["271","700"],["272","188"],["273","73"]]
```

Answer (score 3):

As per the [Flot FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/flot/source/browse/trunk/FAQ.txt):

> Q: Flot isn't working when I'm using JSON data as source!
>
> A: Actually, Flot loves JSON data, you just got the format wrong.
> Double check that you're not inputting strings instead of numbers,
> like [["0", "-2.13"], ["5", "4.3"]]. This is most common mistake, and
> the error might not show up immediately because Javascript can do some
> conversion automatically.

You need to change your output JSON so there are no quotes, i.e.:

```
[[253,5],[254,32],[255,10],[256,50],[257,1],[258,2],[259,100],[260,38],[261,2],[262,20],[263,2000],[264,500],[265,400],[266,10],[267,50],[268,9],[269,200],[270,40][271,700],[272,188],[273,73]]
```

However, this may not do it, it needs to be in a format similar to [this](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/data-japan-gdp-growth.json), so:

```
{
 "label": "example",
  "data": [[253,5],[254,32],[255,10],[256,50],[257,1],[258,2],[259,100],[260,38],[261,2],[262,20],[263,2000],[264,500],[265,400],[266,10],[267,50],[268,9],[269,200],[270,40][271,700],[272,188],[273,73]]
}
```